# How to get a random image using ARKit framework?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {

    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
    let arrayOfImages = ["Photo1", "Photo2", "Photo3", "Photo4", "Photo5", 
                         "Photo6", "Photo7", "Photo8", "Photo9", "Photo10", 
                         "Photo11", "Photo12", "Photo13", "Photo14", "Photo15", 
                         "Photo16", "Photo17", "Photo18", "Photo19", "Photo20", 
                         "Photo21", "Photo22", "Photo23", "Photo24", "Photo25", 
                         "Photo26", "Photo27", "Photo28", "Photo29", "Photo30"]
    
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: (arc4random() % UInt32 (arrayOfImages.count)) )
    return node;
}
```

But it says an error saying it:

#### Error:

```
//Can't convert value of type `UIImage` to expected argument type string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let arrayOfImages = ["Photo1", "Photo2", "Photo3", "Photo4", 
                     "Photo5", "Photo6", "Photo7", "Photo8", 
                     "Photo9", "Photo10", "Photo11", "Photo12", 
                     "Photo13", "Photo14", "Photo15", "Photo16", 
                     "Photo17", "Photo18", "Photo19", "Photo20", 
                     "Photo21", "Photo22", "Photo23", "Photo24", 
                     "Photo25", "Photo26", "Photo27", "Photo28", 
                     "Photo29", "Photo30"]

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfImages.count)))
let Image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[randomIndex])
let Texture = SKTexture(image: Image)
let Sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:Texture)
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work it now says,
Cannot convert value of type UInt32 to expect argument type string.

If you have any other suggestions I would be happy to hear them

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the line which takes index and get array element. now try a new one.

Comment: Thanks for that the array is working now, but I have another problem. In the same phrase when I return the node it says "Error Expected declaration."

This is the code I would be very grateful if you could help me out. Thanks a lot Ben

"func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {

\\Code

};return node;                          ERROR Expected declaration"